# Save JIRA project variable in a List

Tags: java, jira

Is there a way to save `CustomField.getAssociatedProjectObjects()` values in a list?
I have tried something like this:

```
List<Project> associatedProjects = CustomField.getAssociatedProjectObjects();
```

But this does not work. I receive error: "cannot find symbol".

Answer (score 0):

Most likely CustomField is not defined as variable in your code.

Please refer [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean) more detail about this error

Also it's a good idea to follow standard naming conventions for variable names. In this case 'customField' instead of 'CustomField'